# how to programatically open an executable in program files?

Tags: python

I am trying to open an executable as follows and running into below error,how to I take care of the spaces between `Program Files` and open this executable?

```
C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\company\\POST\\bin\\POSTConfig.exe")
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**UPDATE:-**

***Also,I want the python process to terminate while the POSTConfig.exe process continues***

Comment: You need to escape the spaces in the file path. Or put it in quotes. As it is, the command wouldn't work if you pasted it into a shell.

Comment: `os.system` doesn't *open* an *executable*. Rather, it *executes* a *shell command*. Huge difference.

Comment: if `POSTConfig` is a command line app you're probably better off with `subprocess`

Comment: Rhymoid  and Wayne - Running the exe from GUI opens an app,I am trying to open that,how do I that then?

Comment: I often wonder how much that space in 'Program Files' has cost the IT industry over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Please run as below:

```
os.system(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\company\POST\bin\POSTConfig.exe"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a raw string, imbed double quotes inside single quotes:

```
os.system(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\company\POST\bin\POSTConfig.exe"')
```

But please look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module instead.

Comment: This works ,the app opens but the command hangs...how to I gracefully terminate the command

Comment: @PythonProg Please update the question to include that you want the Python process to terminate while the `POSTConfig.exe` process continues.